# Сортировка двусвязного списка

Tags: c

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в сортировке. При попытке вызова этой функции программа зависает.

```
     #include<iostream>
     #include"stdio.h"
     #include"conio.h"
     #include"stdlib.h"
     #include"string.h"
     #include <cstring>
     #include <time.h>
     #include <Windows.h>

  struct List
  {
char name[11];
char surname[21];
char number[13];

List*prev;
List*next;
  };
  List*begin = NULL;
  List*end = NULL;

  bool check(List*tmp)//Ввод с клавиатуры
  {
char number[13];
printf("Enter the name,please\n");
scanf_s("%11s", &tmp->name, _countof(tmp->name));
fflush(stdin);
while (strlen(tmp->name)>11)
{
    printf("\nYou type incorrect name");
    scanf_s("%11s", &tmp->name, _countof(tmp->name));
}
printf("\nEnter the surname,please\n");
scanf_s("%21s", &tmp->surname, _countof(tmp->surname));
fflush(stdin);
while (strlen(tmp->surname)>21)
{
    printf("\nYou type incorrect surname\n");
    scanf_s("%21s", &tmp->surname, _countof(tmp->surname));
}
printf("\nEnter the phone number,please\n");
bool ok, cop = false;

do
{

    scanf_s("%13s", &number, _countof(number));
    fflush(stdin);

    ok = true;

    for (int j = 0; j<strlen(number); ++j)
    {


        if (isdigit(number[j]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Don't type number like this!vvedite nomer! \n");

            ok = false;

        }
    }

} while (strlen(number)>12 || ok == false);
for (List*tmp = begin; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
{
    if (!strcmp(number, tmp->number))
    {
        printf("Nomer est'");
        return false;

    }
    else
        cop = true;

}
strcpy_s(tmp->number, number);


return true;
  }
  void add()//Добавление элемента 
  {
List*tmp = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
if (tmp == 0)
{
    printf("Not good!\n");
    exit(1);
}
if (begin == NULL )
{
    if (check(tmp) == true)
    {

        //tmp->flag = true;
        printf("\nYour register succesfully added\n");

        tmp->next = 0;
        tmp->prev = 0;
        begin = end = tmp;
    }

}
else
{
    if (check(tmp) == true)
    {
        //tmp->flag = true;
        printf("\nYour register succesfully added\n");
        tmp->next = 0;
        tmp->prev = end;
        end->next = tmp;
        end = tmp;
    }
}
/*if (end == 0)
{

    if (check(tmp) != false)
    {

        tmp->flag = true;
        printf("\nYour register succesfully added\n");
        tmp->prev = end;
        tmp->next = 0;
        end->next = tmp;
        end = tmp;

    }*/
//}

  }

  void sort() //Сортировка
  {
if (begin != NULL)
{

bool flag = false;
while (!flag)
{
    flag = true;
    for (List*tmp = begin; tmp -> next!= NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    {

        //for (List*p = tmp->next; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        //{


        if (strcmp(tmp->surname, tmp->next->surname) > 0)
        {
            std::swap(tmp->surname, tmp->next->surname);
            std::swap(tmp->name, tmp->next->name);
            std::swap(tmp->number, tmp->next->number);
            flag = false;
        }
        if (strcmp(tmp->surname, tmp->next->surname) == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(tmp->name, tmp->next->name) > 0)
            {

                std::swap(tmp->surname, tmp->next->surname);
                std::swap(tmp->name, tmp->next->name);
                std::swap(tmp->number, tmp->next->number);
                flag = false;
            }
        }


        //}

    }
}
}
    printf("\nAfter sort\n");
    for (List*tmp = begin; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)
    {


            printf("Name:%11s", tmp->name);

            printf("\nSurname:%21s", tmp->surname);

            printf("\nNumber:%13s", tmp->number);
            printf("\n");

    }

  }


  int main()
  {
  add();
  sort();
system("pause");
return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Отладчик в помощь.

Comment: Вы уверены, что меню и ввод с клавиатуры нужны? Если вы сумеете воспроизвести проблему без них, и укоротить код, найдётся больше желающих в нём разобраться.

Comment: Странно, что код не вылетает. У вас в `if (strcmp(tmp->surname, tmp->next->surname) > 0)` разыменовывается `NULL` на последнем элементе.

Comment: А интересно, доходит ли код до `sort`?

Comment: VladD, как сделать, чтобы не разименовывался?

Comment: Если `tmp->next == NULL`, то это последний элемент в списке и текущий шаг не должен произойти вовсе.

Comment: for (List*tmp = begin; tmp->next != NULL; tmp = tmp->next)?

Comment: Угу, должно подойти по идее.

Comment: Но всё же, посмотрите, доходит ли код до `sort` вообще. (Выведите в начале `sort` что-то на консоль.)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


struct List {
   char  name[11];
   char  surname[21];
   char  number[13];
   List* prev;
   List* next;
};

void List_Add(List**, List**, const char*, const char*, const char*);
void List_Clear(List**, List**);
List* List_Sort(List*, List**, int (*pfn_s)(List*, List*));


int compare(List* a, List* b) {
    int ret = strcmp(a->surname, b->surname);
    if(ret > 0)
         return 1;
    else if(!ret && strcmp(a->name, b->name) > 0)
         return 1;
    return 0;
}



int main(void){
    List*  begin = NULL;
    List*  end   = NULL;

    List_Add(&begin, &end, "all",  "wolf", "300");
    List_Add(&begin, &end, "bob",  "wolf", "300");
    List_Add(&begin, &end, "bla",  "tiger", "300");
    List_Add(&begin, &end, "buk",  "wolf", "300");
    List_Add(&begin, &end, "zed",  "tiger", "300");
    List_Add(&begin, &end, "alt",  "wolf", "300");
    List_Add(&begin, &end, "blur", "tiger", "300");
    List_Add(&begin, &end, "aaa",  "wolf", "300");

    begin = List_Sort(begin, &end, compare);

    for(const List* i = begin; i != NULL; i = i->next){
         cout << i->name   << '\t' << i->surname << '\t'
              << i->number << endl;
    }

    List_Clear(&begin, &end);
    return 0;
}



//добавление в конец списка
void List_Add(List** begin, List** end, const char* name, 
             const char* surname, const char* number){

    List* ptr = new(nothrow) List();
    if(ptr != NULL){
        strcpy(ptr->name, name);
        strcpy(ptr->surname, surname);
        strcpy(ptr->number, number);
        ptr->next = NULL;
        ptr->prev = NULL;

        if(*begin == NULL)
            *begin = *end = ptr;
        else {
            (*end)->next = ptr;
            ptr->prev    = *end;
            *end = ptr;
        }
    }
}


// удаление всего списка
void List_Clear(List** begin, List** end){
    List* tmp, *ptr = *begin;
    while(ptr != NULL){
        tmp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
    *begin = *end = NULL;
}


// сортировка
List* List_Sort(List* lst, List** end, int (*pfn_s)(List*, List*)){
    if((lst == NULL) || (lst->next == NULL))
         return lst;

    List* ptr, *next, *tail;
    List* iter = lst;
    List* last = lst;

    ptr = next = tail = NULL;

    List* tmp = lst;
    while((tmp != NULL) && (tmp->next != NULL)) {
        last = iter;
        iter = iter->next;
        tmp  = tmp->next->next;
    }
    last->next = NULL;

    lst  = List_Sort(lst,  end, pfn_s);  
    iter = List_Sort(iter, end, pfn_s);

    for(; (lst != NULL) || (iter != NULL); ) { 

        if(iter == NULL) {
            next = lst;
            lst  = lst->next;
        } else if(lst == NULL) {
            next = iter;
            iter = iter->next;
        } else if((*pfn_s)(lst, iter)){
            next = lst;
            lst  = lst->next;
        } else {
            next = iter;
            iter = iter->next;
        }

        if(ptr == NULL) 
            ptr = next;
        else
            tail->next = next;

        next->prev = tail;
        tail       = next;
    }

   *end = tail;
   return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Вы поменяли алгоритм с пузырька на mergesort. :) И не проверяете длину в `List_Add`.